# Block Ads via AirPort

Tags: iphone, ipad, airport, adblock

Is there any way to block ads via an Apple Airport? I'd rather block all ads that way so that I can block ads on my iDevices.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Airport base station's DNS to a service such as OpenDNS. Then make an account with OpenDNS and set up a blacklist.

Answer (score -1):

Dnsfool supports adblocking. I found it on google. Seems a bit slow. But its free.